# How can I call the method of class in a jar through terminal?

Tags: java, class, methods, jar

I have a jar file which includes classes. I need to call the method of a class which is in the jar file through the terminal. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you write code to call a method on a class in a JAR, it means it has to be in your application's CLASSPATH.  If you mean running a main method in an executable JAR it has to be in the JAR manifest.

Comment: @duffymo, Thank you. The class does not have main method, So it is not a Runnable jar. It is normal jar. Using this jar I need to call the method through the terminal not eclipse.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it from the command line unless you write a class with a Java main to call it.  You have to start a JVM somehow; that requires a main method.  Write a new class of your own that calls the method you want and execute that.

Comment: @duffymo, Thank you. You told like anyway we need main method to run a jar. Is it right?

Comment: Any Java application runs in the JVM using a main method of your choosing.  You need one, either in the class you specify or as the entry point into an executable JAR.

Comment: @duffymo, Ok I understood. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call the classical `main` method of a class from the terminal, given that it is defined in the JAR's manifest.

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know how to run code that uses a class/method from a jar, in terminal.

If your code (`HelloWorld.java`) uses a method from `your.jar`, this is how you can compile/run your code and call that method from within `HelloWorld.java`:

On Linux :

```
javac -classpath your.jar:. HelloWorld.java 

java -cp your.jar:. HelloWorld
```

On windows :

```
javac -classpath your.jar;. HelloWorld.java 

java -cp your.jar;. HelloWorld
```

Comment: Here You run the class.For example the Helloworld.java has method Display(). That Display method return something. So I need to call that Display() method which is in Helloworld.java. The Class file of Helloworld.java is in my jar.

Comment: So you need to create a class with Main method and in that call the Display method which is in a class that's in the jar

Comment: Anyway we need main method. Without main method we can't use the jar. Is it right?

Comment: Yes that is right. If you externally want to call a method from jar, you need a Main method

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and response.